# how to configure Angular 2 systemJS localStorage

Tags: angular

I want to use Angular 2 locanStorage with SystemJS. I have followed the steps in,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-2-local-storage  &
https://github.com/phenomnomnominal/angular-2-local-storage/issues/20

I have used the 1st mentioned **map** and **package**

also came up with an error:

(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost/meServer/node_modules/angular-2-local-storage/dist/angular-2-local-storage.js

then I changes the main path in packages to **main: ./index.js** in systemjs.config.js it solved the above error.

but when I use below code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LocalStorageService } from 'angular-2-local-storage';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './app/page-body/register/register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app/page-body/register/register.component.css']
})

export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {  

  }

  signUp = function() {

    var data = {
        firstName: this.fname,
        lastName: this.lname,
        email : this.email,
        password : this.password,
        streetNumber: this.streetNumber,
        streetName: this.streetName,
        city: this.city,
        zip: this.zip,
        country: this.selectedcountry,
        phone: this.phone,
        appId: this.appId
    };
    console.log("data : " + JSON.stringify(data));

    this.localStorageService.setItem('appLocalStorageUser'+this.appId, JSON.stringify(data))


}


}
```

this issue came up:
TypeError: this.localStorageService.setItem is not a function

Comment: Please share your localStorageService code

Comment: no its not a service i have just named in as that. I have followed the above mentioned tutorials.

Comment: hi I was able to fix it by removing **setItem** and use only **set**. but nothing is saves in the local storage.

Comment: You can try to use `zoomsphere/ngx-store` instead